# Can't close modal box by clicking outside of the modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, addeventlistener

I have modal boxes that I open this way.

```
<div class="modal-open" data-modal="modal-window-one">Modal1</div>

var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-open");
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
var thisBtn = btn[i];
thisBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
var modal = document.getElementById(this.dataset.modal);

modal.className = "modal-reveal";  
}, false);
}
```

And I am trying to have this modal close by clicking anywhere outside of this modal which has opened.

Here is my code.

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-reveal');
if (event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box){
    box.className = "modal-hidden"; 
}
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?  No console error & I can't figure out why this code won't work.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mspsys/z46woxv0/

Comment: Use code snippet or jsfiddle. It will be easier for others to help if they could run and edit your code without copying it and pasting somewhere.

Comment: Here is my fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/mspsys/z46woxv0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-reveal');
```

to something like:

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-reveal')[0];
```

`.getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection`. You need to get one element.

Comment: get outta here!! 

yeah, I knew that!!!! 

LOL  I am so embarrassed.

I had changed getElementsById() to getElementsByClass.  & I didn't notice that.  Thanks.  I feel like an idiot now. haha

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-reveal');
    if (event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box){
        box[0].className = "modal-hidden"; 
    }
});
```